# Generic view UpdateView from django tutorial does not save files or images

Tags: django, file, upload, django-views, django-generic-views

UpdateView does not save files or images anywhere, what can be the problem?

settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=""
```

article_form.html:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
class updatingexample(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['file1','file2','photo']
```

url.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns=[
path('<int:pk>/upd/', updatingexample.as_view(),name="ugh")
]
```

models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/',blank=True)
    file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads',blank=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('polls:ugh', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})#back to itself
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types though gives explanation how to save with not empty MEDIA_ROOT directory path

Answer (score 4):

Just add on your form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

So it'll end like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

And I also suggest that set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

And add it at the end of your urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: "name static is not defined" where from to import?

Comment: Forgot that, here it is: `from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Comment: I also added field file=models.FileField(blank=True) just in case

But when I press on link to uploaded file, I have error. It parses URLs to find the image only among them. Does it require any view?

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/painsignals.csv
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/
admin/
The current path, media/painsignals.csv, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add the `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` on your main urls (I supposed would be mysite/urls.py)?

Comment: unfortunately to mysite/polls/url.py (polls is a name of my app), thank you for telling exact location. Thank you! Everything finally works!
Where did you know about use of +=static in the first place? Know-how or from simple tutorial?

Comment: Django documentation is your friend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.